# Runtime of random recursive program

Tags: probability, recursion

I just wrote a simple recursive program together with my kids using Snap!
It works like this:

Draw a V shape.
At each of the ends draw either a small shape or another V-shape.

The chance of drawing another V-shape is p.

Question: What can be said about

- the average number of Vs drawn in one run
- the probability that the number of Vs is infinite (the program never ends).

Comment: See Branching process and extinction problem

Comment: Look at this: http://pub.ist.ac.at/~oajanki/book-030-033.pdf

Comment: @Paul Thanks. that contains the answer. Do you want to write one? Otherwise I'll do it myself.

Comment: @JensSchauder Go ahead